# Do tougher targets count as multiple kills in challenges?

Tags: prototype-2

In Prototype, challenges that required you to accumulate X kills within a certain timeframe  rewarded multiple kills for tougher targets (for instance, killing a tank would increase your kill count by 10).

One of the very first Radnet challenges in Prototype 2 would have you kill 30 targets with a grenade launcher within 30 seconds. Seeing how I have an obsessive compulsive disorder with challenges, I am really aiming to get this done, but have yet to find a sufficiently large mass of targets with which to accomplish this feat. However, if vehicles do count as more kills, I might be able to get this done.

So do the mechanics from Prototype carry over, or do I need to simply wait until I find a mass of targets on which to unleash explosive fury?

Answer (score 1):

- 1 Enemy - 1 point
- 1 Tank - 1 point
- 1 Heli - 1 point
- 1 Hydra - 1 point
- 1 Goliath - 1 point
- 1 Alex Mercer - 1 point

What I'm saying is, anything you kill, be it a tank or a enemy, everything counts as 1 kill.

(I tested this out)

Comment: Good to know. I imagine you used science to come by this answer? Adding how you came to this conclusion would really improve the answer.